# Rails cart checkout with Wepay-rails gem, avoid opening security hole on return from checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce

I have been trying to setup the wepay-rails gem https://github.com/adamthedeveloper/wepay-rails with my rails app, and have been successful in doing so however I have realized that because of my setup, it is possible for a user to proceed through part of their order, and then open a new tab, create a new order, and then go back to the first tab which allows them to finish their checkout on the first item, but mark the second item as paid.

I have followed the guide in the readme in order to achieve my current setup:

```
class Purchase::CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  include WepayRails::Payments
  def index
    begin
      @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    rescue
      redirect_to :root
      flash[:warning] = "You do not currently have any pending orders."
      return
    end
    @item = Item.find(@order.item_id)
    checkout_params = {
      :amount => @order.total.to_f,
      :short_description => "Order",
      :long_description => "Your order for #{@order.quantity} #{@item.name.pluralize(@order.quantity)} ",
    }
    init_checkout_and_send_user_to_wepay(checkout_params)
  end
end
```

And the controller which users are redirected to on return:

```
class Purchase::FinalizeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Fetch the WepayCheckoutRecord that was stored for the checkout
    wcr  = WepayCheckoutRecord.find_by_checkout_id(params[:checkout_id])

    @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    @order.wepay_checkout_record = wcr
    @order.paid = true if wcr.state == 'authorized'
   @order.save

    redirect_to :root, :notice => "You have completed your purchase."
  end
end
```

The security issue itself is really obvious, if you change the session ID while in the middle of the order, then on return the wrong order is approved. The problem is there is no value returned from init_checkout_and_send_user_to_wepay that there is no value I can use to tie the order and the checkout record together right away. Am I using this plugin wrong, or just missing something obvious?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Have you tried storing the order id in the `checkout_params`, then retrieve it from there instead of the session?

Comment: Any extra information provided in the checkout_params ends up saying parameter is unexpected